# Getting GPS to display my package subfolders

Tags: ada, gnat

My GPS does not display the subfolders under "src" although they exist and are non empty. When I try to create a new subfolder from within GPS, it gets created but does not show under "src". I am using (community) GPS version 20180523 on Windows 10.

I have tried the following.
(1) I fiddled around with the folder display options in the top right corner of the project tab with no success.
(2) I aggressively hit the refresh button.
(3) I created the subfolders I want in Windows explorer.

How can I get my folder-organised code to show correctly in GPS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your project properties GUI, go under Sources->Directories and check the "Include Subdirectories" checkbox.   To add it manually to your GPR file, open it and add "/**" to the end of your Source_Dirs option:

```
for Source_Dirs use ("src/**");
```

Comment: That was the solution to my problem. Thank you very much.